How is the ! used in Microsoft Access queries?
The "bang" or exclamation point is a logical operator.
Just to follow up on a previous question, is it problematic to use "!" with Microsoft Access queries to specify tables and columns?  And, why?
From copilot:

you show me more examples? Copilot Using the web Certainly! Here are
some additional examples illustrating the usage of exclamation marks
(!) in Microsoft Access queries:
Calculations with Form Controls: Suppose you have a form named
frmSales with two textboxes: txtQuantity and txtUnitPrice. You want to
calculate the total price based on user input. You can create a query
like this: SQL

SELECT [frmSales]![txtQuantity] AS Quantity,
       [frmSales]![txtUnitPrice] AS UnitPrice,
       [frmSales]![txtQuantity] * [frmSales]![txtUnitPrice] AS TotalPrice FROM SomeTable;


AI-generated code. Review and use carefully. More info on FAQ. In
this query, [frmSales]![txtQuantity] and [frmSales]![txtUnitPrice]
refer to the values entered by the user in the respective textboxes.
Filtering Based on Form Controls: Let’s say you have a form named
frmFilters with checkboxes for filtering data. You want to retrieve
records based on the user’s selections. You can construct a query like
this: SQL

SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE [frmFilters]![chkHighPriority] = True   AND [frmFilters]![chkShipped] = False;


AI-generated code. Review and use carefully. More info on FAQ. Here,

[frmFilters]![chkHighPriority] and [frmFilters]![chkShipped]

correspond to the checkbox values set by the user. Joining Tables with
Form Controls: If you have a form that allows users to select criteria
for joining tables, you can use exclamation marks to reference those
selections. For instance: SQL

SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID WHERE [frmJoinCriteria]![cboOrderStatus] = 'Shipped';


AI-generated code. Review and use carefully. More info on FAQ. In
this query, [frmJoinCriteria]![cboOrderStatus] represents the user’s
choice from a combo box on the form. Remember that the exclamation
mark simplifies referencing frontend objects within your queries,
making your Access applications more dynamic and interactive. 

From what I can see, the ! has a specific meaning in Access, but no meaning in SQL, aside from being a logical operator.

! in these cases is a separator which divides the collection name and its child object (collection member) name.

thanks, Akina.  So, within the context of Access, it's okay and not a problem?

Within MS Access code this is OK. [frmFilters]![chkHighPriority] is more clear than Forms("frmFilters").Controls("chkHighPriority")

Excellent, and thanks for the additional info.  That adds to my knowledge.
